# Identify html tags for image, video in text and convert them into images, videos while laying dynamically

Tags: iphone, html, dynamic-data

In my app I need to lay some text which I'm getting from a parsed data. Currently I'm currently laying it in a label. The problem is there are going to be some html tags indicating an image [along with its url] and videos etc in that plaintext. What is a good way to handle this identifying images and videos tags and laying corresponding images and videos along with rest of the plaintext dynamically?

EDIT:

Suppose I'm having following text

```
<img alt="" src="http://www.abc.com/editorial/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/hattos-150x150.jpg" title="Graduation" class="alignnone" width="150" height="150" />
For many, graduation is the time when they start thinking of their career planning.    Many of you know that they want to make a difference, but don't know how to go past that statement.
```

Then while displaying I want to display an image indicated by the url in place of

```
<img alt="" src="http://www.abc.com/editorial/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/hattoss-150x150.jpg" title="Graduation" class="alignnone" width="150" height="150" />
```

and
display

```
For many, graduation is the time when they start thinking of their career planning.    Many of you know that they want to make a difference, but don't know how to go past that statement.
```

as it is below the image. And this should happen at runtime. There might also be a video url in place of image url.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: The question is not clear for me. What kind of data you are getting ?
Why there is an URL ? What is that Label ? Can you post a sample code base to understand ?

Comment: The data I'm getting is plaintext data. In that data, there're going to be embedded tags say for image a tag like <img src="http:....">MyImage</img>. So while displaying the text I need to keep the plaintext data as it is and display the image indicated in html tag as an image. This should happen at runtime.

Comment: @neha first, img elements don't have a closing tag (</img>) so an image tag wouldn't contain text like that anyway. You **could** use alt-text though. Your question is still unclear. Are you trying to say  , "how do you display the image **and** make its alt-text visible on the page too?"

Comment: @Evan Plaice You are right in saying img elements don't have closing tag. Thanx for correcting me. PLease check my edited question.

Comment: @neha I guess what I'm missing is, what exactly are you trying to create?

Comment: @Evan Plaice I'm trying to create a table cell detailedview which is displayed on cell tap. In this detailedview, I want to display some data which I'm obtaining directly from nsxmlparser. This data can contain simple text, images[in the form of url], videos[in the form of url] etc. I want to display whatever there is dynamically e.g. if there's an image indicated in the data by <img scr="...">, then I have to display that image instead of displaying <img src="...">. If  it's normal text "abc", then that text is displayed directly.

Comment: So, what I want is to display content dynamically depending upon its type.

Answer (score 0):

If you see an "img" element, create your custom `DetailView`. In your "detail" view, pass the address in which will be found in the attributes property of the "img" element using  `[[element attributes] objectForKey:@"src"];` Use the address to download and populate a `UIImage`. The contents in the <p> element (the block tags are missing in your example) can be passed to a `UILabel` or `UITextView` whichever is appropriate. If you see a video tag, create an `MPMoviePlayerController` using `initWithContentURL:` with the "src" attribute and push onto the view stack.